# Using #pragma detect_mismatch to ensure a DLL uses the correct statically linked library

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, linker

I have a static S.lib that is used by my D.dll.

I'm trying to use #pragma detect_mismatch to make sure that both were compiled under the same release or debug settings.

I've followed Holger Grund's instructions here
http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Boost-and-Microsoft-s-SECURE-SCL-td3025203.html

dumpbin on S.lib shows:

```
 Linker Directives
 -----------------
 /FAILIFMISMATCH:"COMPILED_DEBUG=1"
 /INCLUDE:_dll_impl_interface_mismatch_check
 /DEFAULTLIB:"MSVCRTD"
 /DEFAULTLIB:"OLDNAMES"
```

I compile D.dll successfully, which should not happen.

dumpbin on D.dll's D.lib shows:

```
Linker Directives
-----------------
/FAILIFMISMATCH:"COMPILED_DEBUG=2"
/INCLUDE:_dll_impl_interface_mismatch_check
/DEFAULTLIB:"uuid.lib"
/DEFAULTLIB:"uuid.lib"
/FAILIFMISMATCH:"_MSC_VER=1600"
/FAILIFMISMATCH:"_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL=2"
/DEFAULTLIB:"msvcprtd"
/DEFAULTLIB:"MSVCRTD"
/DEFAULTLIB:"OLDNAMES"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I accidentally defined the symbol 'dll_impl_interface_mismatch_check' in BOTH my static library and my consuming DLL.  This meant that the symbol was not looked for in the static library S.lib, and the mismatch directive was never found.  I think.

Comment: What are you asking? What is the problem?

Comment: Maybe you should add the actual `#pragma detect_mismatch` line from your attempt to use it. And of course, as Erik already said, clarify what exactly you want to know, since this isn't entirely clear either.

Comment: "I compile D.dll successfully, which should not happen."  The actual detect_mismatch line is unimportant.

Comment: This is an interesting linker capability that I never heard of before - MS needs to document it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just guessing here - I'll have to experiment with this tonight.

Holger Grund's instructions are designed for objects that depend on the DLL.  In your case the DLL depends on the static lib.

So, I'm guessing that you want the `_dll_impl_interface_mismatch_check` object to be added to the static lib rather than the DLL.  So instead of:

```
extern "C" const char dll_impl_interface_mismatch_check=0;

cl /c /Zl foo.cpp
lib D.lib foo.obj
```

try:

```
extern "C" const char dll_impl_interface_mismatch_check=0;

cl /c /Zl foo.cpp
lib S.lib foo.obj
```

Comment: @Cat: Wow - you were actually able to verify this that quickly?

Comment: I found the answer before you answered. :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to build a string with the preprocessor that represents your build settings, and use that string with `#pragma detect_mismatch`.

E.g.

```
#if defined(_DEBUG)
    #define FOO_DEBUG_PART "_debug"
#else
    #define FOO_DEBUG_PART "_release"
#endif

#if defined(_MT)
    #define FOO_CRT_PART1 "_MT"
#else
    #define FOO_CRT_PART1 "_st"
#endif

#if defined(_DLL)
    #define FOO_CRT_PART2 "_DLL"
#else
    #define FOO_CRT_PART2 "_LIB"
#endif

// ...

#define FOO_BUILD_SETTINGS  FOO_DEBUG_PART  FOO_CRT_PART1  FOO_CRT_PART2  /* ... */

#pragma detect_mismatch("foo_build_settings", FOO_BUILD_SETTINGS)
```

The IMO better solution though is to use `#pragma comment(lib)` to link to your libraries, and then build a similar string and use it as part of the file name of the lib:

```
// build FOO_BUILD_SETTINGS like above
#pragma comment(lib, "mylib" FOO_BUILD_SETTINGS)
```

That way you *cannot* use the wrong library (unless you either change the code or the lib is created with the wrong file name ... or renamed afterwards). And of course, if you're as paranoid as I am, you can always do both :)

Comment: +1 for a good idea, I can't do this just yet.  I'm just quickly editing some build settings for a convoluted legacy code base, as some junior developers keep mixing debug and release code.

Comment: I know the problem from when I started at my current employer. We had crazy errors stemming from mixing debug and release code all the time. Since then we switched to linking almost everything via "autolink.h" files which use the technique outlined above (minus the `#pragma detect_mismatch` since we're still using VS 2005). We're using the same tags in the file names of the .dll files too. I can only recommend it, eliminates a lot of problems. Maybe you can do something similar in new projects.